# Finding the length of the non-equivalent side of an isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9CE8.png)

I was told that the 3rd side (x) of this triangle is equal to:

x = 2*L*sin(5°)

Can you explain how someone might reach this conclusion? I was trying to use the law of cosines and got a much longer answer than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to overcomplicate the problem!

Drop an altitude from the vertex to the midpoint of the side containing $x$.

You should now have two identical triangles with hypotenuse $L$, and leg $\displaystyle \frac{x}{2}$. The top angle should also be $5º$.

[image]

Now, using the relationship that $\displaystyle \sin A = \frac{\text{opposite from angle}}{\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{L}$.

We rearrange to get $\displaystyle L\sin A = \frac{x}{2}$, and $x = 2L\sin A$.

Therefore, $\boxed{x = 2L \sin 5}$.

---

How did your friend get $\sin 10$ in the answer?

Comment: I made a typo, I meant to put 5 degrees instead of 10. I will edit my question to fix this. Thank you for the great explanation.